# When to call NHibernate Rollback?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate to insert some data into Table A. I want to update the status in Table B if the Table A transaction fails. How do I check if it has failed?

Below is my current code:

```
// Add userId to Receiver
Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
receiver.User = User.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(listItem.Value));
receiver.Notification = Notification.GetById(notification.NotificationId);
receiver.Save();
```

Where do I call the NHibernate Transaction? If it fails where do I call NHibernate Rollback and update the Table B status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Official NHibernate documentation on Exception handling: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions

```
using ( ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession() )
{
    using ( ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction() )
    {
        try
        {
            // Do your save/update here for Table A

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            // Your save or update failed so this is where you
            // could capture that info and update your Table B

            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

From what I remember, you don't actually have to call tx.Rollback() because when your code leaves the using blocks, it will do that automatically but again, I can't remember exactly. Give it a try and if it doesn't behave as I just described, you can manually rollback in the catch.

Comment: Thanx for the answer but I cannot use var, I'm using .Net 2.0

Comment: @HardCode :) Okay... you can always replace the var keyword with the actual Type. I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession())
using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // do some work
    tx.Commit();
}
```

or manually

```
ISession session = factory.openSession();
try
{
   // do some work
   session.Flush();
   currentTransaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   currentTransaction.Rollback();
   throw;
}
finally
{
   session.Close();
}
```

Take a look [NHibernate transactions](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/09/08/part-9-nhibernate-transactions.html) for more details

Comment: URL for "NHibernate transactions" as of 11 Feb 2016 is http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/09/08/part-9-nhibernate-transactions.html